# RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. in my flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, scheduler, flask-mail

I'm trying to schedule sending email from my flask application with this function :

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.start()

def email_job_scheduling():
    to="abdellah.ala@gmail.com"
    subject="summary projects"
    message="your summary projects"
    send_email(to,subject,message)

scheduler.add_cron_job(email_job_scheduling, day_of_week='tue', hour=12, minute=55)
```

this is how i declare app in my file **init**.py, is there any relationship or must i add schedule function in this file.

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
db = SQLAlchemy()
mail = Mail()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=10)

    db.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    return app
```

but I receive this error,

> Debug mode: off  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to
>   quit) Job "email_job_scheduling (trigger: cron[day_of_week='wed',
>   hour='9', minute='57'], next run at: 2019-12-11 09:57:00)" raised an
>   exception Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/abdellah/Documents/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py",
>   line 512, in _run_job
>       retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)   File "/home/abdellah/Documents/SUPPORT-STS/project/app/admin/views.py",
>   line 29, in email_job_scheduling
>       send_email(to,subject,message)   File "/home/abdellah/Documents/SUPPORT-STS/project/app/emails.py",
>   line 11, in send_email
>       mail.send(msg)   File "/home/abdellah/Documents/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mail.py",
>   line 491, in send
>       with self.connect() as connection:   File "/home/abdellah/Documents/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mail.py",
>   line 508, in connect
>       return Connection(app.extensions['mail'])   File "/home/abdellah/Documents/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
>   line 348, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)   File "/home/abdellah/Documents/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
>   line 307, in _get_current_object
>       return self.__local()   File "/home/abdellah/Documents/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/globals.py",
>   line 52, in _find_app
>       raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg) RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
>   needed to interface with the current application object in some way.
>   To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context(). 
>   See the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you have not specified an application context you should create it.
This is because it is necessary to define all the necessary resources within the Flask application.
The documentation explains perfectly in which cases and how you should use a context application in Flask.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/

If you post more code I could be more helpful.

I will try to find a solution by the way:

```
from flask import g

def email_job_scheduling():
    a = "abdellah.ala@gmail.com"
    subject = "summary projects"
    message = "your summary projects"
    send_email (to, subject, message)

def get_scheduler():
    if "scheduler" is not in g:
    g.scheduler = Scheduler()
    g.scheduler.start()
    returns g.scheduler

with app.app_context(): #add the necessary resources
    scheduler = get_scheduler()
    #add another code if you need to set another resource

#This piece of code I think is in the main
scheduler.add_cron_job (email_job_scheduling, day_of_week = 'tue', now = 12, minute = 55)
```

Comment: i have no idea where can i place this code, i put all the error code in previous question

Comment: See the edit solution, i can't see the real code but i think that it's something right

Comment: I have added the content of my init.py file in the first question... is there any modification can i do in this file?

Comment: I insist on saying that it is necessary to initialize all the resources that will be used each time for each request. I strongly recommend that you review the documentation and various examples. However, I am attaching an article that could help you clarify the issue. http://kronosapiens.github.io/blog/2014/08/14/understanding-contexts-in-flask.html

Comment: thank you Roberto, I test the solution, but it give me the same error...